# Confusing step in proof of divisibility by $7$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I am reading the proof of the divisibility rule for $7$  [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Divisibility_rules/Rule_2_for_7_proof) (Aops page),but I can't see how $k-2n_0 \equiv 2n_0 +6k $ is derived.

I've tried to derive it by this: $$2n_0 +6k \equiv 2n_o +7k-k \equiv 2n_0-k, $$
but how can I get from this to $2n_0+6k \equiv k-2n_0$?

Comment: $$7\mid 10k+n_0\iff 7\mid 2(10k+n_0) =20k+2n_0$$

$$\iff 7\mid (20k+2n_0)-7(3k)=-k+2n_0$$

Comment: thanks,but why in the comments ?You don't give me the opportunity to accept your answer and show my gratitude :).

Comment: @user236182 Please type up your hints as an answer in order to close the question. Until then (or whenever someone else decides to answer in greater detail), [this community wiki answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3049719/104041) referencing you will suffice :)

Answer (score 0):

*This community wiki answer is to point out that [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1623818/confusional-step-about-proof-of-divisibility-by-7?r=SearchResults#comment3310855_1623818), posted by @user236182 (who is invited to post an answer), answers the question.*

*Summarising it:*

> $$\begin{align}
> 7\mid 10k+n_0 &\iff 7\mid 2(10k+n_0) =20k+2n_0 \\
> &\iff 7\mid (20k+2n_0)-7(3k)=-k+2n_0.
> \end{align}$$